# Sketching phase portrait

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

$\dot{x}=-2x-2y$

$\dot{y}=-x-3y$

Equilibrium point is $(0,0)$. Eigenvalues are $\lambda_+=-1$ and $\lambda_-=-4$ which have corresponding eigenvectors $2\choose -1$ and $1 \choose 1$ respectively. The point is a stable node.

So when sketching the diagram, there will be a line through the origin with gradient $1$ and a line through the origin with gradient $-1/2$. The arrows on these lines are going to be inwards towards the equilibrium point. How do I sketch the phase paths and isoclines?

Comment: find the nullclines

Comment: I have never heard of that before

Comment: The fixed point is of [this type](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/PhasePlane_files/image004.gif). Since $\lambda_-<\lambda_+$, the trajectories are tangent to the eigenvector $2\choose -1$ hence the linked image rotated by $-90$° is your phase plane.

Comment: why did you rotate it? in our solutions, it is not rotated.

Comment: Surely you noted that this is an image randomly picked on the internet. You should rotate it so that the two eigenvectors on the image roughly correspond to the two eigenvectors in your case. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: @Did could you have a look at my thread here please, it really concerns straight line paths and eigenvectors. I really need to understand this. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1239558/eigenvectors-question

Comment: @Did Never mine, I think I know now. How to get the straight line paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with your analysis, you should first find the regions of the plane that have a zero partial derivative. Namely $\dot x, \dot y = 0$.

Setting $\dot x = -2x - 2y = 0 \implies y = -x$ is a set of points where $\dot x = 0$.
Setting $\dot y =-x - 3y = 0\ \  \implies y = -\frac{x}3$ is a set of points where $\dot y = 0$.

While a point on the line $y=-x \implies \dot x = 0$, we can evaluate $\dot y$ along this point
to get $\dot y = -x-3(-x) = 2x$, so along this line, $x>0\implies\dot y >0, x<0\implies \dot y<0.$

A similar argument can be made about evaluating $\dot x$ along the curve which has $\dot y = 0$.
Drawing these lines, and a vector field along these 'nullclines' can give a lot of information about the behavior of systems of differential equations.

Comment: I really don't understand. what would $\dot{y}=-4x$ even look like on a xy plane? since it is not simply $y=-4x$/

Comment: You don't need to worry about what it looks like, but now you have a function where you can evaluate what the slope is at every point. So if we consider $(x,y) = (1,-1)$ we know that $\dot x = 0$ and $ \dot y < 0 $.

Comment: so $\dot{y}<0$ and $\dot{x}=0$ but what does that mean? how can you tell the slope by these two?

Comment: You normally would want to think about $\frac{\dot y}{\dot x}$ for the slope but since $\dot x = 0$ here you would just have a slope pointing straight downwards along $y = -x$

Comment: Do at point (1,-1) it goes straight downwards and then curves left then along the line of $2\choose -1$ towards the equilibrium point?

Comment: I realized a typo in original answer. At $(1,-1)$ slope should be straight upwards, as it would be at any point along $y=-x, x > 0$. If you graph the two 'nullclines' and then draw tangent lines on them for each quadrant, you should find some patterns in the overall behavior. It then becomes a task of identifying what happens at $(0,0)$ since both derivatives are $0$.

Comment: yeah I see why you say straight upwards.

Comment: about the phase paths, how would you know where they come from and where they cant come from? I mean in general terms where there is multiple equilibrium points. and like where they cannot cross a certain line?