# Eigenvectors question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

$x'=x-2y$

$y'=4x-x^3$

Equilibrium points are $(2,1),(-2,-1),(0,0)$

Consider equilibrium point $(2,1)$: Let $X=x-2$ and $Y=y-1$. Subbing this into the main and eliminating all the nonlinear terms gives:

$x'=X-2Y$

$y'=-8X$

Giving the eigenvalues $\lambda_{\pm}=1/2 \pm \sqrt{65}/2$ so $(0,0)$ is a saddle point. The Linearization Theorem implies $(2,1)$ is a saddle point for the nonlinear system. To find the straight line paths in the $XY$-plane, we can either find the eigenvectors $v_{\pm}$ or by subbing $Y=kX$ into the equation for the phase paths $$\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{-8X}{X-2Y}$$ so $2k^2-k-8=0$ giving $k_{\pm}=1/4 \pm \sqrt{65}/4$, giving the straight line paths $$Y=k_{\pm}X$$ 
Writing in terms of original terms, we get $$y=k_{\pm}(x-2)+1$$ Now that we got these lines, what exactly do they mean? What is the point of them because I found all of the isoclines and used the fact that the $(0,0)$ is an unstable spiral and found roughly the direction of flow on the phase paths.

How do I know which line corresponds to which eigenvalue??? I really need to know this!!

Comment: isn't it the tangent to the stable and unstable manifold of your equilibrium point ?

Comment: sorry what is a manifold??

Comment: well, the linearized system is (locally) conjugated to the non linearized system. so the non linearized system admits an invariant stable curve of points converging in the future to your saddle point, and an invariant unstable curve of points converging in the past to the saddle points. those curves admit tangents at the equilibrium points, and they are given by the eigenvectors you found

Comment: sorry wait a minute. can you just tell me about the straight line paths I found, which were two of them, how do I know which line corresponds to which eigenvalue?

Comment: these are really eigenvectors of the differential of your vector field. to find out which eigenvector corresponds to which eigenvalue is just basic linear algebra

Comment: im not following... what do you mean? id probably know if you please elaborate a bit more

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvectors tell you the direction of the flow locally around the fixed point. By locally, I mean, *very* close (how close? as close as you can be) to the fixed point.

Here's a picture:

[image]

The pure green and pure blue arrows represent the eigenvectors. The green eigenvector is associated with the negative eigenvalue, and the blue eigenvector is associated with the positive eigenvalue.

Comment: so whichever one is the more dominant eigenvalue, the corresponding eigenvector is gonna have phase paths along from that one?

Comment: @snowman actually both, only one will be going towards the equilibrium point and one will be "leaving" the equilibrium point

Comment: @snowman as  Glougloubarbaki said, both eigenvectors will indicate trajectories. Remember that the negatives of the eigenvectors are also eigenvectors, so that will help you "draw the other side". The trajectories however, won't necessarily be "one leaving" and "one entering". That will only be the case for saddle fixed points. For attracting nodes they will both be "entering" and for repelling nodes, they will both be leaving.

Comment: @snowman I added a picture to the answer to help make it clearer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @user89 The pic is for $XY$ right? So for $xy$, it would just be translated to point (2,1) correct? Also how did you know which line is associated with which eigenvalue? Because I calculated the lines -not eigenvectors. If I calculated the eigenvectors, it is obvious which eigenvalue it is associated with.

Comment: @snowman Do you realize that you played exactly the same strange play when I posted [a similar diagram solving your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1238335/)?

Comment: @snowman I think you should find the eigenvectors as well.